# How best to "return an error" from a Worklight procedure?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have written an adapter with a few simple procedures. In some circumstances I need to signal the caller that something went wrong. I have tried a few approaches ..

- **Throwing an exception**: the text of the exception gets back to the caller via the onFailure callback (great), but comes wrapped in the module name and line number of the exception. TMI.
- **Returning an object where isSuccessful = false**: this works like a charm and it's delivered to the caller via the onFailure callback.

For example:

```
return {
    isSuccessful: false,
    errors: ["No servers available"]
};
```

[This article from IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1212_paris/1212_paris.html) however explicitly warns against doing just this, though doesn't describe an alternative - can you?

Comment: For what it's worth, I would do the following. Server: `return {error: "No servers available"}`, Client: `if (response.error) { /*handle error*/ } else { /* handle success*/ }`. The idea is to create a custom error object (like in your example) and check the failure case (that custom error object exists) before the success case. Use any keys you want, just not the ones Worklight uses (i.e. `isSuccessful`) because the behavior may change in later releases.

Comment: In addition [to the blog post you've found](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1212_paris/1212_paris.html), I would also take a look at another recently published blog post titled [Handling Backend Responses in Adapters](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/handling_backend_responses_in_adapters?lang=en). With the second blog post you should have better understanding on how to best "return an error" in Worklight Adapters.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this blog post?
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/handling_backend_responses_in_adapters?lang=en

The blog post details:

For `invokeProcedure` (client to adapter):

- What does an invocation response look like?
- When will isSuccessful be true?
- When will isSuccessful be false?

For `invokeHttp` (adapter to server):

- What does a backend invocation response look like?
- When will isSuccessful be true?
- When will isSuccessful be false?

Based on the conditions you will provide in the response to the client, you can then return errors in more clarity.